# If/else statement in foreach query in neo4j

Tags: if-statement, foreach, neo4j

I would like to duplicate every node in my graph by using foreach loop. I try to use if/else statement to create specific kind of node - (:Node) if n:Node has 'Node' label and (:Road) if r:Road has 'Road label. How to fix this query?

```
MATCH p=((n:Node)-[:STARTS]-(r:Road)-[:ENDS]-(z:Node))
FOREACH (x in nodes(p) | 
WITH CASE head(labels(x)) 
WHEN 'Node' 
THEN
CREATE (:Node {name : x.name, subID : ID(x)})
ELSE 
CREATE (:Road {name : x.name, subID : ID(x)}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any FOREACH, you can just create them :

```
MATCH p=((n:Node)-[:STARTS]-(r:Road)-[:ENDS]-(z:Node))
CREATE (:Node {name : n.name, subID : ID(n)})
CREATE (:Road {name : r.name, subID : ID(r)})
```